# Is there a GZIP J2ME library?

Tags: java, java-me, gzip

Is there a gzip compression library that will work on J2ME?

Answer (score 4):

Try [Jazzlib](http://jazzlib.sourceforge.net/), although it's GPL, and seems like it hasn't been updated for a while. Another option is to try and lift the source from [libgcj](http://gcc.gnu.org/java/index.html) (which is what jazzlib did).

[J2SE](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/) includes [`java.util.zip`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html) which can compress/decompress gzip files, but the [MIDP 2.0](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/) specification does not include a `java.util.zip`. And looking at the Java 6 source code for `java.util.zip`, each class seems to call native methods, which means you can't just lift what's there and download it to a J2ME device.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to find a J2SE implementation and try to convert it to J2ME. I wouldn't expect it to be hard, but still it would require some effort.
How about [this one (jazzlib?)](http://koders.com/?s=jazzlib&scope=VFGKBNSSK8ZA7W9RU13ANURN4C&la=Java)?

Answer (score 1):

Original jazzlib is for J2SE only.

Jazzlib ported to j2me is available here: http://code.google.com/p/staff/downloads/list?q=jazzlib

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check out: http://code.google.com/p/compress-j2me/. Uses only 7k (~5k after obfuscation). Compression is under developement.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [this one](http://www.java4ever.com/index.php?section=j2me&project=apime&menu=download&lang=)? (I haven't, but found it when googling.)

Answer (score 0):

I've seen successful use of http://www.tinyline.com/utils/ which gives you a gzipinputstream useful for http communications.