# How can zip and unzip on j2me

Tags: java-me, zip

Please post me simply code that can create zip and unzip, i need it now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [compress-j2me](http://code.google.com/p/compress-j2me/) library. See also [Is there a GZIP J2ME library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095400/is-there-a-gzip-j2me-library)